# I migrated from rails 3.2 to 4.1.7 and get OrmAdapter Error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, orm

- Rails 4.1.7
- Ruby 2.1.4p265 (2014-10-27 revision 48166) [x86_64-darwin14.0]

Migrate from rails 3.2 to 4.1.7 and get this error when launching console:

undefined method `whitelist_attributes=' for # (NoMethodError)

```
 $ rails s

 => Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.1.7 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting


    /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing'/Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/orm_adapter-0.5.0/lib/orm_adapter/adapters/active_record.rb:81: warning: already initialized constant ActiveRecord::Base::OrmAdapter
    /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/orm_adapter-0.5.0/lib/orm_adapter/adapters/active_record.rb:81: warning: previous definition of OrmAdapter was here


 : undefined method `whitelist_attributes=' for #<Class:0x007fc524a5dca0> (NoMethodError)
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:110:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:109:in `each'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:109:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/base.rb:326:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/base.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/orm/active_record.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/rails_projects/farma/config/initializers/devise.rb:22:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise.rb:293:in `setup'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/rails_projects/farma/config/initializers/devise.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:648:in `block in load_config_initializer'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:647:in `load_config_initializer'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:612:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `each'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `block in <class:Engine>'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:418:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:427:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:417:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:411:in `call'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:411:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/rails_projects/farma/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/rails_projects/farma/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/rails_projects/farma/config.ru:in `new'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/rails_projects/farma/config.ru:in `<main>'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:50:in `app'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:130:in `log_to_stdout'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:67:in `start'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
        from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Try to run rake rails:update

Comment: @UncleGene $ rake rails:update
rake aborted!
No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)
/Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'

Comment: Where did you run it from? You have to be in your rails root